# Toggle show/hide divs if data.entities.length > 0, tertiary operator doesn't work on Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to toggle visible/hidden two different DIVs if `data.entities.length > 0` and this is what I'm doing:

```
if (data.entities.length > 0) {
    var toggle = data.entities.length ? true : false;

    // if condition is true then this will show otherwise it will hides
    $('#resultadoNorma').toggle(toggle); 

    // this is the reversal process
    // if condition is true then this will goes hide otherwise it will goes show
    $("#sinResultadosBuscarNormas").toggle(!toggle); 
}
```

But it's not working since none DIV is show/hide not matter what happen with condition, what is wrong? Can I use tertiary operator in Javascript?

Comment: Your tertiary does not make sense. It would always yield true, because that's the condition of the `if` that is necessary for it to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the conditional operator is inside the `if()` statement, which only succeeds if there's a positive `.length`, so `toggle` will always be `true`.

You should remove the `if()` statement.

```
var toggle = data.entities.length ? true : false;

$('#resultadoNorma').toggle(toggle); 
$("#sinResultadosBuscarNormas").toggle(!toggle);
```

---

Or just get rid of the conditional, and pass the `.length` directly. Probably good idea to coerce to a boolean though.

```
$('#resultadoNorma').toggle(!!data.entities.length); 
$("#sinResultadosBuscarNormas").toggle(!data.entities.length);
```

Comment: It's not working at all, this `{"message":"No se encontraron normas","entities":[]}` is where `data.entities.length` comes from and for this case meaning no entities so length should be zero `$("sinResultadosBuscarNormas")` is not show and `$('#resultadoNorma')` is not hide

Comment: @ReynierPM: You have it reversed. When `.length` is `0`, `sinResultadosBuscarNormas` should show, and the other should hide. That's the way your logic is written in your code anyway. If you want it the other way around, then reverse the boolean values.

Comment: But if you have some other meaning for "not working at all", then describe what that means. Are you saying neither show nor hide? You have to communicate that information.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong from the beginning and sorry for that, the idea: if `data.entities.length > 0` then `#resultadoNorma.show && #sinResultadosBuscarNormas.hide` otherwise the reverse `#resultadoNorma.hide && #sinResultadosBuscarNormas.show` (this is some kind of pseudo code). I should said both `#resultadoNorma && #sinResultadosBuscarNormas` are hides by default meaning `style="display:none"`. I have inverse the logic as `$('#resultadoNorma').toggle(!data.entities.length);` and `$("#sinResultadosBuscarNormas").toggle(!!data.entities.length);` and it's not working meaning logic is wrong

Comment: Ok, if you want to show `resultadoNorma` when `.length > 0`, then the original logic is correct. If it isn't working, then there's some other issue, and you'll have to provide a full demonstration of the problem. But the only problem shown in the question is fixed with this code.

Comment: Nevermind, I was the issue :-(, leave the `.toggle()` inside the conditional and for that wasn't working, get out made the code works fine, thanks